# Create new worksheet based on cell but ignore empty cell

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I would like to create a new worksheet in my workbook; name based on the information in the C column (starting at C4) of the "Summary" Worksheet. I have the following VBA so far but when it gets to a blank cell it stops. I need it to ignore blank cells and continue. Any help?

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAListTEST()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("C4")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new workbook
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'renames the new workbook
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I also need to automatically fill the new worksheet with information from the "Summary" worksheet. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("C4")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new workbook
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'renames the new workbook
Next MyCell
```

by

```
set MyRange=range(sheets("Summary").[c4],sheets("Summary").cells(rows.count,"C").end(xlup))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    if len(mycell.text)>0 then 
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new workbook
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'renames the new workbook
    end if
Next MyCell
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still stops when it hits two empty cells in a row